# Convert bmp to jpeg using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap, jpeg, client-side

I already manage to manually create the bitmap of an uploaded image, by manipulating the color channels to obtain an 8 bit image. Now, i'm in the need of converting the bitmap to jpeg but i need to maintain the bit depth (8 bits depth single-channel)
I can't use Canvas since when the conversion is done the resulting file is 24 bit depth.
Anyone knows if this possible to use JavaScript to do this conversion, so i can have all the image manipulation on the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused between [color depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) and pixel format, and I'll admit it's confusing, because this Nbits nomenclature is used everywhere while having completely different meanings.

E.g what we call PNG-24 is actually 8 bits * 3 channels (RGB) and PNG-32 is 8 bits * 4 (RGBA).

But to put it simply, JPEG format doesn't support indexed colors, it is always (at least)* TrueColor: 3 channels * 8bits => ~16.77 millions colors.
<sup>*since v9 it actually supports up to 12 bits per channel</sup>

What you want to do (single 8bits channel => 256 colors) is not possible, because the JPEG format itself doesn't support it.

Note that because of how JPEG works (merging visually similar colors) that wouldn't make any sense anyway to save a 256 colors image in JPEG. The JPEG algorithm will create back new colors that weren't in your original 256 bitmap, and you might very well end up with a bigger file than its bitmap equivalent.

So if you really want an 8 bit image with a single channel (256 colors), then look at formats that do support [Indexed colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color).
PNG is one of them, but indeed canvas won't help you there since the Canvas API only supports PNG-32 (8 bits per channel RGBA).
GIF is an other one, but I think only Safari does support exporting to GIF from a canvas element...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From the research that i've done, i seen some examples, using design programs, where it's possible to create a JPEG file with 8 bit depth.  For example, if you use Photoshop you can save a file with 8 bit depth (single channel color). My project requirements are to set an image in JPEG, grayscale with 256 colors (8 bit depth). At this moment i've already created a bitmap with a single color channel but i need to convert it to jpeg without losing the bit depth and i would like to do that on the client-side. Could someone help me?

Comment: @PatriciaNascimento once again, jpeg format itself doesn't support 8bits color single channel. It's old but https://forums.adobe.com/thread/376358 the option you have in PS applies only for the image you have in ps (psd). Once converted back to jpeg, its a 24 truecolor again.

Comment: Maybe i'm confusing the concepts but looking at video example its possible  to create a JPEG with 8bit depth. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo0eqCEFCl4) I´ve tried to reproduce the steps mentioned on video and the final image was as expected a JPEG with 8 bit depth (single-channel). Now i'm trying to do the same thing but using Javscript.

Comment: No, what this video show is to go from a (possibly TIFF) 16bits per channel to an 8 bits per channel JPEG. But there are still 3 channels x 8 bits. Just look, try to do the inverse, set it it to 16bits per channel. You'll see that PS won't allow you to save it as JPEG, unless you tick save as copy. Now, check the saved file => reported as 8bits.

Comment: Hmm... Now I see that you were talking about grayscale images in the first comment? Is that true? In this case, maybe it is indeed possible to have a single channel... But the video is definitely not showing this.

Comment: Yes, its possible with those properties but i'm having some problems converting to JPEG and maintain the bit depth

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja2zh.jpg

The saved file had this properties. It is a JPEG gray image.